# In which versions of Visual Studio do .NET full framework projects support PackageReference?

Tags: visual-studio, packagereference

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

> .NET full framework projects support PackageReference

In which versions of Visual Studio is that?

Comment: VS2017 required.

Comment: @HansPassant from 15.0?

Comment: It is somewhere around 15.7.4 right now, do update.

Comment: starting [15.1](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html#what-about-other-project-types-that-are-not-net-core) so you already have support for a long time.

Comment: is the question answered or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With **Visual Studio 2017** and **.NET Core**, we have improved the
>   NuGet package management experience by introducing the
>   **PackageReference feature in MSBuild**. PackageReference brings new and improved capabilities such as deep MSBuild integration, improved
>   performance for everyday tasks such as install and restore,
>   multi-targeting and more.

Starting with the [first Update (15.1)](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html#what-about-other-project-types-that-are-not-net-core) you get support for other types.

> **What about other project types that are not .NET Core?** You can get a first look of what will come in the next NuGet update. **Hop on to
>   the Visual Studio 2017 Update 1** Preview 2 bandwagon.

So if you run the current 15.7.x you already have support even if Visual Studio 2017 still uses `packages.config` by default. With [15.7 VS2017 does also have a convert tool](https://blog.nuget.org/20180409/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference.html) to migrate the old `packages.config` way to new style:

[image]